# Are Extension methods too expensive?

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-2.0

How much will it cost for my programs performance if i add Extension methods to it?
Will it work slower or may be will load slower?
Thanks.

Comment: this is something you could check yourself by writing a 10 lines program

Comment: Does it matter if execution is slightly slower?

Comment: +1 to Andrey, I agree, it would be more enlightening for programmers to investigate very specific performance concerns with a quick throw away performance test than to start a question on SO.

Comment: @Andrey and @marr75, though certainly true, accruing knowledge on the matter in a public place means that software developers _as a whole_ don't waste countless human-hours writing 10 line programs for a question that is asked once, answered once and is now available via google in 20 seconds.

Comment: @Andry and @marr75. Why you spent your software developers human-ours on writting unmeaning sequence of words?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How much will it cost for my programs
>   performance if i add Extension methods
>   to it? Will it work slower or may be
>   will load slower?

There will be no performance hit.  Extension methods are really static methods.

Answer (score 4):

An extension method is just syntactic sugar applied to a static method.

In theory, a static method is faster than a non-virtual instance method (no need to check for null `this`) which in turn is faster than a virtual instance method (no need for looking up the implementation to call).

In theory also, optimisations could get rid of these differences. It's also overstated in terms of static when it comes to extension methods, since the object is probably going to be dealt with in such a way as requires a null-check (whether explicit or implicit to the ways it is use) anyway.

In practice, the chances are that whatever the extension method does will have much, much more of an impact that whether it's extension or instance.

Answer (score 4):

I quickly performance tested this using some integer extension methods in a REALLY long running loop and found that in the cases I tested, the performance was generally identical. When debugging or running unoptimized assemblies, extension methods ran about twice as slowly as my control cases, this makes sense because the debugger can't inline these methods and has to keep track of the callstack, etc.

So, in an assembly ready for release, no performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly won't load slower, as loading a program is not dependent on the execution paths in the program.

As for running more slowly? Only measuring the time taken for the extension method and the non-extension method will show for certain. I suspect the difference won't be significant even if it's actually measurable.

The important consideration should always be "does the extension method make my code clearer and easier to understand and maintain".